# Linux dd create multiple iso files

Tags: linux, backup, dd

I want to create an iso from an external hard drive. 
I used this command:

sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=usb-image.iso

It works, however, the disk is large (700 GB), and i dont have space on my laptop to store that much.
I was thinking about creating multiple iso files (each file 5 GB for example), this way, I can manage them by storing some parts on other drives.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: It's more of a fit for SuperUser, consider using block size and count (see the manpage for details)

Comment: [first google try](http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/applications_gui_multimedia/splitting_and_merging_files_using_dd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the `split` program to split the output from `dd` into different files. You can adjust the split size as you see fit (look at the `5000m` argument):

`dd if=/dev/sdb | split -b 5000m - /tmp/output.gz`

This will yield files like `/tmp/output.gz.aa`, `/tmp/output.gz.ab`, etc.

Additionally, for further space storage, you can gzip your archive midstream, like this:

`dd if=/dev/sdb | gzip -c | split -b 5000m - /tmp/output.gz`

Later, when you want to restore, do this:

`cat /tmp/output.gz.* | gzip -dc | dd of=/dev/sdb`